# Pairs of users with same set of followers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I am still fairly new to mySQL and I am having a hard time making a query where I can find the users with the same set of followers.

Here are my tables and for the subscribes table, my logic is that user1 subscribes to user2

```
CREATE TABLE user(
user_id integer primary key auto_increment,
username varchar(500) not null,
email varchar(500) not null,
password_hash varchar(500) not null,
create_date date null
);

CREATE TABLE subscribes(
  subscribes_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user1_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES user,
  user2_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES user,
  FOREIGN KEY (user1_id) REFERENCES user (user_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (user2_id) REFERENCES user (user_id),
INDEX (user1_id),
INDEX (user2_id)
);
```

Thank you

Comment: there is no go solution for your requewst , to check ifor any users that share the same subscribers. it will be possble to loop over all user1_ids and check (with a loop over all users if the share all the user2_ids. like you can see easily, that will that lots of time and resources and can only be doen in a procedure

Comment: are the sets "IDENTICAL or are you talking subsets as well? Example (user 1 followers (3,4,5)  user 2 has followers 3,4,5,6) are they a match? or must it be exactly the same? and this sounds doable provided we know the rules for "same set"  This gets a little dicey if user 1 follows just 1 person and 300 other people aslo follow that 1 person... How do we know.  Mock up sample data and expected results to help us visulaize your need.